# Python socket chat server only listens to one client

Tags: python, sockets, chat

Hi I am working on a self made chat server using python and sockets. I was trying to finish the entire thing without a tutorial but I have been stuck on this for about 4 days now and decided to get some help.

I have gotten far enough that the server can have clients connect to it, it can store there data, and receive and send out messages, My problem is that after connecting two clients and sending about 4 messages the server stops receiving messages from one of the two clients. But the client that can no longer send messages can still see incoming messages from the other client

Here is the code for my server

```
import socket
import threading


HEADER = 100
PORT = 1234
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = "utf-8"
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "DISCONNECT"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

#list of all connected clients
cl = []

#is run when i new client connects
def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")
    
    connected = True
    
    while connected:

            msg = conn.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT)

            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                 connected = False

            for i in range(threading.activeCount() - 1):
                                    
                print("          ")

                conn = cl[i]
                    
                print("          ")

                conn.send(msg.encode(FORMAT))
                
    conn.close()
        

#scans for new clients    
def start():
    server.listen(5)
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        client_con = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        client_con.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount() - 1}")     
        print("   ")
        #adds new client to clients list
        cl.append(conn)
        
        
print("[STARTING] server is starting...")
start()
```

And here is the code for my client

```
import socket
import threading


HEADER = 100
PORT = 1234
FORMAT = "utf-8"
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "DISCONNECT"
SERVER =  socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER,PORT) 
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)


#get users name that is show befor message's
def get_info():
    
    name = input("whats your name: ")
    NAME = name
    NAME = NAME + "-"
    

    
    return NAME

#sends messags's to server
def send_msg():
    
    NAME = get_info()

    while True:
        
        print("    ")
        msg = input("type your message: ")
        print("    ")
        
        msg = NAME + " " + msg
        
        message = msg.encode(FORMAT)

        client.send(message)
        
#recives messages from server 
def recs():
    while True:
        print("  ")
        
        msg_rcv = client.recv(5000)
        print(msg_rcv.decode(FORMAT))
        
        print("  ")
          

send = threading.Thread(target=send_msg)
rec = threading.Thread(target=recs)

rec.start()
send.start()
```

Thank you for reading and any help is very apricated have a great day! <:

Answer (score 0):

Well turns out i finally found my issues after making a flow chart to help me visualize where an issue could occur.

the issue was in my server and had to do with the `con` variable in this strip of code

```
            msg = conn.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT)
          

            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                 connected = False

            for i in range(threading.activeCount() - 1):
                                    
                print("          ")

                conn = cl[i]
                    
                print("          ")
                
                conns.sendall(msg.encode(FORMAT))
```

i just needed to use a diffrent var for sending the message so here is the working server code

```
import socket
import threading


HEADER = 100
PORT = 1234
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = "utf-8"
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "DISCONNECT"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

#list of all connected clients
cl = []

#is run when i new client connects
def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")
    
    connected = True
    
    while connected:
            
            msg = conn.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT)
            print(f"[MSG IS]--> {msg}") 

            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                 connected = False

            for i in range(threading.activeCount() - 1):
                                    
                print("          ")

                conns = cl[i]
                    
                print("          ")
                
                conns.sendall(msg.encode(FORMAT))
                
    #conn.close()
        

#scans for new clients    
def start():
    server.listen(5)
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        client_con = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        client_con.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount() - 1}")     
        print("   ")
        #adds new client to clients list
        cl.append(conn)
        
        
print("[STARTING] server is starting...")
start()


#we need to find a way to send a message from a client to all other clients!
```

all i had to do was change one of the conn to conns so it would not mix things up!